# SSRS IIF IsNothing Calculation

Tags: reporting-services, iif, calc

I have the following statement input as the background color of a cell which works fine, but if that cell is blank my code returns a shade of red.

```
=IIF(Fields!DBS_Next_Due___App_1.Value <= Today(), "#FF9696", 
 IIF(Fields!DBS_Next_Due___App_1.Value <= dateadd("d",180,Today()), "#FFFF96", "White"))
```

I tried to deal with the blanks with the  `isnothing` setting ,but i can't get the syntax correct. Any help would be appreciated

```
=IIF((IsNothing(Fields!DBS_Next_Due___App_1.Value <= Today())  , “#FF9696”, 
   IIF(IsNothing(Fields!DBS_Next_Due___App_1.Value <= dateadd("d",180,Today())) , "#FFFF96",
     AND NOT IsNothing(Fields!DBS_Next_Due___App_1.Value), "WHITE"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to check for null and OR it with the <=.

```
IIF(IsNothing(Fields!xxx.Value) OR Fields!xxx.Value <= Today())
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Ross